# Is there a commonly supported way to make a skewed "frosted glass" effect in CSS/SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I'm looking to make a website splash page. The page will have one background that will be cut off on the left side with a slanted div, say at a constant 110 degrees from the horizontal (or equivalent, keep reading). This div will blur the background behind it and will allow for content to be put on it, like text. See the [YouTube Brand Resources page](https://www.youtube.com/yt/about/brand-resources/): instead of having a plain white background on the left, I would like that to blur the background picture that sits underneath it.

I've not yet found a way to put all of the information I've found together in a way that works and is supported by most browsers. For example, I recently tried a skewed div that shared a background with the parent container, like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947156/how-do-you-skew-a-div-and-keep-the-background-image-unskewed) asked about, but CSS clip paths aren't commonly supported yet, and a white div won't *cut it* for my use case (to be clear, this solution ends with a skewed background image).

Using [SVG clip paths and filters](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jXZNLK) (see below) gets me close, but as you can see, I don't know how to make sure the image and the SVG fills the screen and lines up with the background behind it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="splash">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <filter id="blur" x="0" y="0">
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1"></feGaussianBlur>
        </filter>
        <clipPath id="clip">
            <polygon points="0,0 100,100 0,100"></polygon>
        </clipPath>
        <image clip-path="url('#clip')" filter="url('#blur')" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" xlink:href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/11/17/22/15/tree-3822149_960_720.jpg"></image>
    </svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sass:

```
html, body
  position: relative

  margin: 0
  overflow-x: hidden
  height: 100%

.splash
  position: absolute
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  overflow: hidden

  background-image: url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/11/17/22/15/tree-3822149_960_720.jpg")
  background-size: cover
  background-repeat: no-repeat
  background-color: lightgrey
  background-attachment: fixed

  svg
    position: absolute
    width: inherit
    height: inherit
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure how to make this less broad. Would you rather have me close this question and ask multiple variants of the form "How can one make a full screen splash page divided in half by an angled div at 110 degrees from the horizontal with {SVG,CSS,HTML,clip-path,background images}?" and have some be wrong because _I don't know how to?_ Asking in one question seems like the better option to me.

Comment: I don't think this question is too broad, though I would like to see this with compiled CSS instead of Sass, unless of course your question is specifically how to do it *in Sass*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider skew transform without the need of `clip-path`. here is a basic example where the trick is to specify the correct value of `background-position` to create the illusion of one image.

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/600/800?image=1069);
  background-position:left center;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.skew,
.skew::before{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform-origin:top left;
  transform:skewY(30deg);
  overflow:hidden;
  background-image:inherit;
  background-position:inherit;
  background-size:0 0;
}
.skew::before {
  content:"";
  transform:skewY(-30deg);
  filter:blur(10px);
  background-size:cover;
}

/*to illustrate the separation*/
.skew {
  border-top:1px solid;
}
/**/
.container {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  margin-top:150px;
  padding-left:50px;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="skew"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>some text</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="box" style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/600/800?image=3)">
  <div class="skew"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>some text</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

In case you want the skew to be responsive you can add a small JS code to adjust the angle and always cover half the iamge:

```js
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = 300; /*the height of the box*/
document.querySelector('.box .skew').style.transform="skewY("+(Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg)";
document.querySelector('.box .skew span').style.transform="skewY(-"+(Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg)";

window.onresize = function(event) {
    w = window.innerWidth;
    document.querySelector('.box .skew').style.transform="skewY("+(Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg)";
    document.querySelector('.box .skew span').style.transform="skewY(-"+(Math.atan(h/w)*180/Math.PI )+"deg)";
};
```

```css
.box {
  height:300px;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/600/800?image=1069);
  background-position:left center;
  background-size:cover;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.skew,
.skew span{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  transform-origin:top left;
  transform:skewY(30deg);
  overflow:hidden;
  background-image:inherit;
  background-position:inherit;
  background-size:0 0;
}
.skew span{
  transform:skewY(-30deg);
  filter:blur(10px);
  background-size:cover;
}
/*to illustrate the separation*/
.skew {
  border-top:1px solid;
}
/**/
.container {
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
  margin-top:150px;
  padding-left:50px;
}

body {
 margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="skew"><span></span></div>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>some text</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also make it all in a single <svg> image, using a [<pattern>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern) element to fill half a triangle with the image, and apply your filter on it.

```css
svg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1024" height="200" viewBox="0 0 1024 200" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pat" viewBox="0 0 1024 200" width="100%" height="100%">
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/1024/200?image=1029" width="1024" height="200"/>
    </pattern>
    <filter id="blur">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <!-- background no filter -->
  <rect width="1024" height="200" fill="url(#pat)"/>
  <!-- foreground triangle, blurred -->
  <path d="M0,0L1024,200H0Z" fill="url(#pat)" filter="url(#blur)"/>
</svg>
<div class="container">
  <h1>some text</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I don't know the dimensions of the image?

Comment: @Pheric I can't really see why you won't, but you could build that svg from javascript after loading the image in an HTML <img> element

Comment: it won't work properly if I have multiple pictures at different resolutions in a sideshow or something.